# Python: Guardar cadena en archivo binario y leer la cadena desde el mismo archivo binario

Tags: python, archivo, stream

En primer lugar guardo la cadena en un archivo binario:

```
from os import strerror

cadena_a_codificar ="Esto Es un ejemplo DE cadena ¿?=)("
data = bytearray(len(cadena_a_codificar))

for i in cadena_a_codificar:
                     
        data.append(ord(i))


try:
    binary_file = open('file.bin', 'wb')
    binary_file.write(data)
    binary_file.close()
except IOError as e:
    print("Se produjo un error de E/S:", strerror(e.errno))

# Ingresa aquí el código que lee los bytes del stream.

data2 = bytearray(len(cadena_a_codificar))
try:
    binary_file = open('file.bin', 'rb')
    binary_file.readinto(data2)
    binary_file.close()

    print(data)
    print('\n         **         \n')      

    for b in data2:
        print(hex(b), end=' ')
     
    print('\n         **         \n')     

    for b in data2:
        print(chr(b)+'-', end=' ')
        
except IOError as e:
    print("Se produjo un error de E/S:", strerror(e.errno))
```

La salida de este código es:

```
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Esto Es un ejemplo DE cadena \xbf?=)(')

         **         

0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 
         **
```

Porque no lee el código?:

```
 for b in data2:
        print(chr(b)+'-', end=' ')
```

cómo podría codificar para obtener justo la misma cadena que he codicado en el archivo binario?

Answer (score 2):

#### Analisis

Es la primera vez que veo tan profundamente el funcionamiento de un bytearray, pero por lo que veo, el problema está en como es usado en el código. Para entender, haré un analisis de lo que hace el código publicado:

1. `bytearray(len(cadena_a_codificar))` crea un bytearray lleno de `len(cadena_a_codificar)` bytes vacíos.
2. Agregas al final de esos bytes vacios la cadena codificada caracter por caracter.
3. repites el paso 1
4. readinto lee `len(data2)` bytes y sobreescribe los bytes anteriores del nuevo bytearray desde la posición 0. Que por supuesto son los bytes vacíos del paso 1.

#### Solución a primera vista

Un código que podría funcionar, y que demuestra que no se requiere por el momento un bytearray es:

```
cadena_a_codificar ="Esto Es un ejemplo DE cadena ¿?=)("

binary_file = open('file.bin', 'wb')

# creo un objeto bytes a partir de una cadena utf-8
binary_file.write(cadena_a_codificar.encode())

binary_file.close()

binary_file = open('file.bin', 'rb')

# esto lee un objeto bytes, si necesitás que sea mutable, envolvelo con bytearray
data2 = binary_file.read()

binary_file.close()

for b in data2:
    print(chr(b)+'-', end=' ')
```

#### Caracteres no ascii (incluyendo acentos y ñ)

Debido al funcionamiento del código propuesto más arriba, esto no es un problema para la solución inmediata, pero probablemente quieras trabajar archivos binarios más complejos y para eso hay que tener algo en cuenta.

En la base de datos unicode, existen 0x10ffff (1.114.111) caracteres. Pero un byte solo puede llegar al numero 255. Este numero magico que ves sobre todo en videojuegos antiguos es el numero de combinaciones posible de 8 bits (0 y 1) (el 0 cuenta como una combinación posible). Y suele pasar en dichos juegos debido a que el creador no consideró la posibilidad de requerir un número más grande que ese.

Esto implica que para representar caracteres más allá del numero 255, se requieren más bytes (es el bloque más chico en el que Python lee archivos binarios).

bytearray trabaja con bytes, es decir, un caracter unicode podría no abarcar un solo item del bytearray, si no, por ejemplo, 3.

Resulta ahora que al momento de leer una cadena unicode de un archivo binario `len(cadena) == len(bytes(cadena))` suele dar falso. Ahora no nos importa la cantidad de caracteres, si no la bytes. Cuando diga cuanto mide una cadena, me referiré a bytes.

Mi código funciona por que lee el archivo hasta el final y los métodos encode y decode hacen el trabajo duro. Pero que pasaría si querés leer una cadena cuyo final no está en el final del archivo?

#### el modulo struct

Un buen amigo para lidiar con estos escenarios de bytes variables es el modulo de la librería estandar [struct](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/struct.html), que nos permite trabajar con tipos de datos estandar.

Incluso, nos permite calcular el largo de una estructura de datos especifica, lo cual nos permite leer a partes el archivo:

```
import struct
import io

class ByteReader:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def read(self, format):
        return struct.unpack(format, self.file.read(struct.calcsize(format)))

with io.BytesIO(b"hola mundo") as file:
    file = ByteReader(file)

    # Devuelve una tupla incluso si se trata de un solo elemento.
    print(file.read("3s"))
    print(file.read("3s"))
```

No es el punto de esta respuesta realizar un tutorial del modulo (además, ya de por si es muy larga), pero el modulo el facil de entender si tenés noción de que es un byte y hay tutoriales en internet.

#### Cadenas de tamaño fijo

Muchas veces, será util que una cadena en un archivo binario siempre mida lo mismo. Y si mide menos, struct rellenará con un caracter especial que después quitaremos.
A continuación, un ejemplo:

```
string = struct.pack("10s", b"1234567")

print("packed", repr(string))

string = struct.unpack("10s", string)[0].decode().rstrip("\x00")

print("unpacked", repr(string))
```

OJO, recordemos que el 10 es en bytes, no en caracteres.

También podemos usar una [cadena de pascal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-pascal-strings/), que antes de la cadena incluye un byte que indica cuantos bytes hay que leer de una cadena de tamaño fijo. Esto tiene sus pros y contras, pero es util.

```
string = struct.pack("10p", b"1234567")

print("packed", repr(string))

string = struct.unpack("10p", string)[0].decode()

print("unpacked", repr(string))
```

#### Cadenas de longitud variable

Para este escenario, un truco habitual es usar dos "elementos" en el archivo binario:

1. Un numero que indique la medida de la cadena.
2. La cadena en sí.

Código de ejemplo (usando ByteReader):

```
value = b"1234567"

string = struct.pack("h%ss" % len(value), len(value), value)

print("packed", repr(string))

with io.BytesIO(string) as file:
    file = ByteReader(file)

    num = file.read("h")[0]
    print(file.read("%ss" % num)[0])
```

Esto, a diferencia de la cadena de pascal, no requiere rellenar la cadena usando `\x00`, si no que usa el número obtenido para saber cuantos bytes hay que leer luego.